# Iterative slicing

Tags: python, iteration, slice

I am a beginner in programming, I try to learn Python, and I cannot set a correct iterative slincing of my data.
I have this:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
     12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

And I would like to obtain this, i.e I do chunks of 3 items and remove half of them:

```
a = [0, 1, 2,
     6, 7, 8,
     12, 13, 14, 
     18, 19, 20]
```

I tried a for loop with a % condition, but I cannot set the rule to get what I want ...I did not do maths during years so it's probably a very stupid logical error ...

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

for i in range (len(a)):
    if i==0 : 
        a=a
    elif (i-3)%6 == 0 :
        a[i:i+4]=[]     
    else :
        a=a
        
print(a)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: Can you provide sample input/output?

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you have tried

Comment: Please show the for loop you tried.

Comment: Easiest way would be `b = [e for (i, e) in enumerate(a) if (i % 6 < 3)]`

Comment: "I tried a for loop with a % condition, but I cannot set the rule to get what I want ..." Well, can you come up with a slice that gives you the first three elements? The next three? Can you see a pattern in what those slices look like? What if you used, for example, a `range` to generate the values that are different between those slices, then generated each slice, and put them together?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. I have edited your question to remove conversational language, because we are not interested in conversation here, we are interested in *clear questions*. The goal is to have something that other people can find later with a search engine.

Comment: Sidenote: rather than explicitly type out your input list, you could just write `list(range(24))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use list comprehension:

```
result = [val for i in range(0, len(a), 6) for val in a[i:i+3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you want this ?

```
a= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
b = []

for i in range(0,len(a),6):
    for j in range(i,i+3):
        b.append(a[j])

print(b)
```

Comment: Any time you loop over a list and append to another empty list, you should probably be using a list comprehension. `[x for i in range(0, len(a), 6) for x in a[i:i+3]]`

Comment: instead of looping just slice and extend: `for i in range(0, len(a), 6): b += a[i:i+3]`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. Define new array ( or list )
2. Defining a counter variable and a keepItem boolean
3. Loop through the array and add 1 to the counter at every step
4. If the counter is 3 then set it to 0 and flip the boolean value
5. If your keepItem boolean is true then add that item to the new array

I would suggest defining edgecases. For example, what happens when the length of the array is not a multiple of 3?

This should be a good starting point!

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension and integer operations:

```py
[v for v in a if (v // 3) % 2 == 0]
```

This of course assumes that you're working on a sorted list with values from 0-n, as in the example. If you still want to use this method, you can use enumerate, too:

```py
[v for i, v in enumerate(a) if (i // 3) % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: A little bit fragile as it depends on the items in the list being equal to their index.

Comment: The second is nice, I thought of it too ;)